# Чтение файлов в /proc/net на ОС Android

Tags: java, android, файлы

Нужно прочитать файл `/proc/net/arp`, но при чтении у меня возникает ошибка:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/arp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`
Тут - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem написано, что чтение с версии Андроида 10 ограничено, сам запускаю код на Андроид 12, реальноe устройство, все разрешения есть. В файловом менеджере все читается. В чем проблема?

Код:

```
        try {
            File file = new File("/proc/net/arp");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.next());
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Манифест:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Ничего не ограничено. Приведите код ваш

Comment: @ArtyMorris https://pastebin.com/8409bhwe

Comment: Код пишите здесь

Comment: @ArtyMorris, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Манифест ещё приведите

Comment: @ArtyMorris, готово!

Comment: Весь манифест надо, а не разрешения